# List all php cli scripts running in the background

Tags: php, mysql, centos, nohup

I am running some background tasks with php cli using `nohup php app.php &`.How can i list all the scripts that i have sent to the background and how can i forcibly close it?.

My script looks like

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=odesk', 'root', '');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,msisdn from new_r4 limit 44908,50000");
$sth->execute();

while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Will this script i sent to the background stop once i have processed all rows?.

Comment: yes, when it finished, then the process will killed. you can use `ps -aux` to list all of your running processes, and you can use `kill -9 [processnumber]` to kill a process.

Comment: Okay,thanks.I shall wait on it and see. I am on cent os and this showed me line by line `ps aux | less`

Comment: Nope,the processes do not die.